# how to keep all files by unduplicating them

Tags: sha

This is a bit of an odd request as its not necessarily coding related, but I have been using SHA256 to spot duplicate files. Unfortunately for one reason or another all duplicate files need to be kept and need to be amended slightly for a new SHA256 to be generated.

There are many solutions out there that will delete duplicate files etc, but I need a solution that will look for duplicates and as it finds a duplicate, try to unduplicate it.

As I am using pdf, doc and docx files, I was thinking of a solution that adds a blank page at the end of the document with a character. I have been doing this currently manually but something automated would be of much help.

Has anyone come across this issue or know of a possible solution?

Thank you for your help in advance,

Panos

Comment: Are you sure that unduplicate is the correct word? Create, delete, copy, edit, compress a file, and transfer. Somehow unduplicate is your choice to describe something not 100% clear :)

Comment: Hi Krassi and apologies for the confusion.

Essentially, this is what I had in mind;
1. Check file alphabetically by name to get SHA256
2. If the SHA256 exists in any of the earlier files then
3. edit file and add new page with character of some sort that amends the SHA256
4. Add new SHA256 to list and move on to next file

Hope this makes things a little clearer... but this is just an option, not sure if there is anything out there that does this or something similar